# How to add a new div below search bar in the header by creating new module? Magento 2.1.5

Tags: magento2.1.5

I need to add a new div at the bottom of the header. I am using magento 2.1.5.

I want to do this by creating a new module. I checked lots of tutorials. I am able to add a div to the top of the header but not in the bottom. Here is my code:

**view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="header.container">
        <container name="header.containertwo" as="header_containertwo" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="header-mini-container" after="header.panel.wrapper"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="header.containertwo">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.mini.container" template="Header_CustomDiv::test.phtml" after="header.panel.wrapper"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

**view/frontend/template/test.phtml**

```
<div style="border:1px solid red;" id="test123"><p>Text Here  </p></div>
```

The above code adds a div to the top of the header, however I want it at the bottom as in image.
[image]

**Here is the header html code:**

```
<header class="page-header">
    <div class="header content">
        <span data-action="toggle-nav" class="action nav-toggle">
            <span>Toggle Nav</span>
        </span>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 no-pad-left logo">
            Logo here
        </div>
        <div class="block block-search col-lg-5 col-lg-offset col-sm-9">
            <div class="block block-title"><strong>Search</strong></div>
            <div class="block block-content">
                Search form  here
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="compare wrapper">
            <li class="item link compare" data-bind="scope: 'compareProducts'" data-role="compare-products-link">
            </li>
        </ul>
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        <li class="authorization-link" data-label="or">
            <a href="#">
                Sign In    </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Create an Account</a></li></ul></div></div>

        <div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
            <a class="action showcart" href="#" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <span class="text">My Cart</span>
            </a>
        </div>      
    </div>
</header>
```

After adding the move tag as mentioned by Dinesh Yadav  :

```
<move element="header.mini.container" destination="header.panel.wrapper" after="-" />
```

[image]

Comment: you can add your content or div in a static block and display that block below your header via admin

Comment: @Manoj Deswal Please explain more about how to do it.

Comment: share current screenshot of your header and also inspect your header in browser and take screenshot ...... if you have live URL you can share that

Comment: you knows creating block and content in that ... just need to tell how to show that below header ..... is it above navigation or below navigation ?

Comment: you are not using any navigation ?

Comment: No not in the header.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66577/discussion-between-manoj-deswal-and-moe-hammadi).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to move your custom phtml file after search box, try below code

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
      <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test.header" template="Vendor_Module::test.phtml" after="topSearch" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Where to add this code?

Comment: you can put above code after your referenceContainer ends. See my updated answer

Comment: Please check the new image in the updated answer. After aadding the move  tag , the div moved inside the panel wrapper. However i want it below the search bar

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: It is moved to the top of the header. I updated my question and posted the header html code.

Comment: @MoeHammadi , I have updated my answer. I successfully moved my custom phtml file after search box using above code. Ask me if you face any problem.

Comment: Denesh, it doesn't work. It is still at the top.

Comment: Have you checked the position of your custom div in view page source ? Check it using inspect element in browser.